# How to change tooltip on Angular 7/8 from Chart.js

Tags: html, angular, charts, chart.js

I am using Angular & Chart.js (with ng2-charts) on my an app.
With bar chart, by default, when I clicking on a column I get a tooltip as shown :

[image]
I want to change the inside of that tooltip. This is my code :

my-bar-chart.component.html :

```
<div class="container chart-style">
  <canvas baseChart
          [datasets]="barChartData"
          [labels]="barChartLabels"
          [options]="barChartOptions"
          [legend]="barChartLegend"
          [chartType]="barChartType"
          [options]="barChartTooltip"
          style="height:20rem; width:100rem"
          >
  </canvas>
</div>
```

and my-bar-chart.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './my-bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class MyBarChartComponent {
  constructor() { }
  public barChartOptions = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
  public barChartLabels = ['One star', 'Two stars', 'Three stars', 'four stars', 'Five stars'];
  public barChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartData = [
    {data: [28, 39, 42, 19, 8],
    label: 'amount',
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    ],
    borderWidth: 0,
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(221, 221, 221, 1)',
    scaleStepWidth: 1,
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,1,2, 1)',
    }
  ];

  public barChartTooltip = //I dont know
}
```

Comment: what changes did you need tooltip?

Comment: I would like to change the title and square icon.